# Download Extension for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, google-chrome-extensions

I'm looking for an extension to Chrome which has this functionality:

- I have site with links to pdf/html/zip/...
- When I click right mouse button, a context menu appears
- I can click "download all", next I can choose which pdf, html, zip files I want to download.

Do you know any extension with this functionality? In Firefox I have FlashGot for this task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original author of FlashGot states [here](http://forums.informaction.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3802) that the Chrome extensions API is still not adequate.

But all is not lost, as you can try [DM-Bridge / oGet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lfjamigppmepikjlacjdpgjaiojdjhoj) that works in a similar way.

Google also have an extension called [Download Assistant](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mfjkgbjaikamkkojmakjclmkianficch).

Comment: I install Download Assistant + Oribt - it works great:)